# Fading animation in Visual Studio Blend

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I wish to change the actual content of my textblock. I know I can change it by using `textblock.text = "new text"` when an event is triggered. However, is there a way to make it change gradually, i.e. with a fade animation? I tried using Visual Studio Blend, and managed to make objects scale, and rotate, but I have not figured out how to make content of an element change/ apply animation when content of the element changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small example, which consists of a TextBox and a TextBlock. Each time you change the value in the TextBox, the content of the TextBlock fades out and in.

```
<StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtSampleText" Margin="10" Text="This is a Sample Text"></TextBox>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbMessage" Text="{Binding ElementName=txtSampleText, Path=Text, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Margin="10">
            <TextBlock.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:1" From="1.0" To="0.0" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:1" From="0.0" To="1.0"  />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </TextBlock.Triggers>
        </TextBlock>
 </StackPanel>
```